# how to make svn call to post-commit hook async and not wait for it to complete?

Tags: windows, batch, svn, python

I have post-commit.bat hook which contains this

```
d:/mypathtoscript/mypostcommit.py
```

however **when i do commit with tortoise svn it waits for mypostcommit.py to complete no matter what i tried** (and it takes time) i do not want the commit in tortoisesvn to wait until my postcommit.py ends.

so i tried

```
start d:/mypathtoscript/mypostcommit.py
```

however it still waits for it.

anyone knows what i can do?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is by design, see e.g. [Running Subversion post-commit hook as background process](https://serverfault.com/questions/65450/running-subversion-post-commit-hook-as-a-background-process)